# py2app Application closes on open

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a simple ' Hello, World! ' programme in Python 2.7 to play around with py2app. I made the setup.py file and then I ran python setup.py helloWorld.py

Now it created a build folder and a dist folder and inside the dist folder is the .app application of my helloWorld python script.

Now, here is the issues. Everytime that I try to run said .app, it opens and closes instantly.

What is happening? Is it printing Hello, World and then closing too fast for me to see it? Is there a way to prevent it from closing?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: did you find solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

`>> Is there a way to prevent it from closing?"`

this code will wait for user input and after it will closes

```
>>> print 'Hello World'
Hello World
>>> raw_input('press any key to exit')
press any key to exit
''
>>>
```

Comment: Could you explain your code and what makes it an answer to the question posed?

Comment: SO answered "Is there a way to prevent it from closing?" this code will wait for user input and after it will closes.

Comment: @IrfanM if this answer has helped you, could you accept it? thanks.